# Как динамически добавлять окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть интервал, в котором элементы массива отображаются на карте. Хочу к отображаемым маркерам добавить окно информации. Но почему-то метод не срабатывает.

```
var Cicle = setInterval(function() {
  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];


  var markers = [];
  var infowindow = [];
  var num_markers = locations.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < num_markers; i++) {
    markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: locations[i][1],
        lng: locations[i][2]
      },
      map: map
    });


  };

  for (var i = 0; i < num_markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setPosition(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);

    //Данный метод добавения окна с текстом не работает*
    infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow[i].setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow[i].open(map, marker[i]);

  }

}, 15000);
Cicle;
```

Comment: объявляем массив `var infowindow = []`; ....... далее используем [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) .....happy end

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо за подсказку , но если можете более развернутый ответ оставьте

Answer (score 1):

```
var ArrayInfoWindows = [];
var locations = []; // Должен быть заполнен
function init(locati,map,marker){
  for (var i =0;i++;i<maxWindow){
    ArrayInfoWindows[i]=new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    ArrayInfoWindows[i].setContent(locations[i][0]);
    ArrayInfoWindows[i].open(map, marker);
  }
}
init(23,2,2); // Создали 23 Новых окна


/** OR **/
var ArrayInfoWindows = [];
function add(locations,map,marker){
   var Test = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
   for (var i=0;i++;i<locations.length){
     Test.setContent(locations[i][0]);//Не уверен насчет этого
     ArrayInfoWindows.push(Test);
     ArrayInfoWindows[ArrayInfoWindows.length-1].open(map, marker[i]);
   }
}
add(locations,Map,Marker);
```

Comment: Он будет отображаться сразу да без события нажатия ?

Comment: Ну да (только map,marker всегда будут одинаковы)

Comment: нет на самом деле  marker[i]

Comment: он тоже проганяется в цикле

Comment: @elik я добавил 2 вариант, просто я не представляю структуру location и marker

Comment: Секунду я щас поправлю впрос поставю свой метод так как не один из вших способове сработал пересмотрите мой код

Comment: я уже до тебя пробовал так делать но не получалось

Comment: Пожалуйста, выравнивайте код в примере, что бы он был более читабельным.

Comment: Хорошо Юрий учту